# Statistics/Probability Videos for Beginners

Tags: references

There was already [a request for Mathematical Statistics Videos](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485/mathematical-statistics-videos),  but it explicitly asked from people for

> videos that provide a rigorous
>   mathematical presentation of
>   statistics. i.e., videos that might
>   accompany a course that use a textbook
>   mentioned in this discussion on...

So at the same time I am wondering, **what recommendation do you have for stat/prob - 101  - video courses?**

Answer (score 16):

I think a number of the suggestions put forward on the [mathematical statistics video question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485/mathematical-statistics-videos) probably fall in the stats 101 category:

- http://www.khanacademy.org/#Statistics: series of short videos on introductory statistics
- http://www.khanacademy.org/#Probability: series of short videos on introductory probability
- [Math and probability for life sciences](http://www.academicearth.org/courses/math-and-proability-for-life-sciences): A whole university course introducing statistics and probability.
- I also have a [list of maths and statistics videos](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/05/online-mathematics-video-courses-for.html) with a few others.

The Stat 579 Videos on statistical computing in R are also quite good:

- http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p31588910/
- http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p45341752/
- http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p39131597/
- [Factor & reshaping data](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p21949344/)
- [Debugging & data aggregation](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p62985380/)
- [Data aggregation & maps](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p77697317/)
- [Data aggregation & maps (copy?)](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p77697317/)
- [LaTeX and Sweave](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p54242569/)
- [Random numbers, basic Simulations](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p95967207/)
- [Permutations & data from the web](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p80966639/)
- [Text & Patterns](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p51894198/)
- [Databases](http://connect.extension.iastate.edu/p39993940/)

Comment: stat579: Where exactly are the video lectures?

Comment: @gd047 That's sad. stat579 videos appear to have been removed. I've removed the link from my answer.

Comment: Perhaps because this "newer version" is available. http://www.public.iastate.edu/~hofmann/stat480/

Comment: The videos appear to still be available online. I added the links.

Comment: @Jeromy Anglim Ahhh! You did a great job! (I wonder how). Is there any video from stat480 online also?

Comment: +1 For 579, I really enjoyed the videos (I added descriptions for some of the videos)

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest [Statistics 401](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-3474013489970580510&hl=en&emb=1#) (from Iowa State University). 
This is the link for Lesson 1. There are 64 lectures in total. (Here is the [last one](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=3835401745697888723&ei=coO0S9aOOJLF-Qb9kJnnBg&q=Statistics+401%3A+Lesson+64&hl=en&view=3#)). Unfortunately, I haven't found the links gathered together in one page. I think also that lessons 21,26 and 39 are missing. However, I don't remember having any problem in following the course). You can also find the handouts for this class posted [here](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~pcaragea/S401F07/Handouts07.html).

Some other introductory courses in Statistics are:

[Introductory Probability and Statistics for Business](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_details_new.php?seriesid=2009-B-87384&semesterid=2009-B)

[Basics of probability and statistics](http://videolectures.net/bootcamp07_keller_bss/)

[Lesson Videos for Statistics](http://sofia.fhda.edu/gallery/statistics/resources.html)

[2007 SLUO Lectures on Statistics](http://www-group.slac.stanford.edu/sluo/lectures/Stat2007_lectures.htm)

Comment: As of 2013, the ISU statistics 401 videos are marked *private* on YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

GD047 linked to a UC Berkeley video on statistics, and I had another one. It's similar to MIT's Open Courseware (maybe a little lower quality). This one is for the Intro Statistics and Probability Class. It unfortunately only has 9 episodes, but it's free :).

[UC Berkeley STATS 20 Webcast](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_details_new.php?seriesid=2010-D-87392&semesterid=2010-D)

Answer (score 2):

Harvard's Stat 110 Probability taught by Joseph Blitzstein is available on [iTunesU](http://delicious.com/redirect?url=http://itunes.apple.com/us/course/statistics-110-probability/id502492375) or [Academic Earth](http://www.academicearth.org/courses/statistics-110-probability).

Comment: Also available on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely consider the Stats courses on Udacity.

ST101: http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/st101/CourseRev/1

There is also a ST095 course on Udacity, which I would have linked to but the link was blocked in this answer. Replace the 101 in the above link with 095.

EdX, which is a consortium between Harvard, MIT and Berkeley also has a Stats course from Berkeley

http://www.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/Stat2.1x/2013_Spring/about

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I've studied from John E. Freund's Mathematical Statistics with Applications (7th Edition) at Freiburg University. It is indeed a good book, but you would also need a solutions manual to it because the excercises at the end of each chapter are not trivial.

Comment: Does the book come with a video?!