# Good Internet resource for preparation for studying mathematical statistics

Tags: references

I'm going back to university this September and I picked up a course which has some prerequisites

> Mathematics & Statistics (Sci): Sample space, events, conditional
>   probability, independence of events, Bayes' Theorem. Basic
>   combinatorial probability, random variables, discrete and continuous
>   univariate and multivariate distributions. Independence of random
>   variables. Inequalities, weak law of large numbers, central limit
>   theorem.

I've studied statistics many years ago but as I don't use it in my work I completely forgot all of it.  Since there're still a month before September, I think I should make some preparation for my study if I don't want to drop the course.  So is there any good Internet studying resources that I can use to refresh my statistic knowledge?  (I thought about buying textbooks, but they are really expensive)

Comment: Your title asks for *the best resource* while your actual question more reasonable talks about *good internet resources*...

Comment: The list of topics is typical of a first *probability* course. For a decent treatment, you need to look at Internet books/notes that assume at least a first year calculus course, and preferably a little more.

Comment: Mood, Graybill, and Boes (1974), 3rd. ed., is a fantastic text, both for some basic introductory probability useful for mathematical statistics and for a very good introduction to mathematical statistics, itself. [Here](http://www.colorado.edu/Economics/morey/7818/7818readings.html) is a link to the entire book, which has been out of print for almost 40 years. I'm not quite sure what the copyright restrictions are for this text, under the circumstances. The link is hosted by a professor at University of Colorado-Boulder, though that's no guarantee that due diligence has been performed.

Comment: see also this question on online videos for mathematical statistics: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485/mathematical-statistics-videos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a lot of this in [*Virtual Laboratories in Probability and Statistics*](http://www.randomservices.org/random/) from the University of Alabama in Huntsville.

Answer (score 0):

A basic probability book is what you're after.  Do you have library access?  If so, go with Sheldon Ross, a first course in probability.  Or, Introduction to Probability by Richard Schaeffer.  I'm recommending books here, because studying probability requires patience and concentration.  In my experience those things don't go hand in hand with the internet.

As Andre noted, In my experience math/stats is a different and very difficult course which focuses on things like convergence, sufficiency, biasedness, etc.  Most people who take grad classes in statistics I imagine would know this.  I'm confused why a department would call a probability course math/stats.  (I'm not faulting the OP, I just think the department is wrong to label the course this way.)