# Is statistics.com class worth the money?

Tags: machine-learning, references

I'm debating taking some classes on statistics.com and was curious if anyone has taken classes there or knows any one who has or has any suggestions for good ways to learn stats/machine learning on the cheap-ish and on-line.

NOTE: I'm already signed up for Andrew Ng's ML class for spring '12.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some resources I gathered for myself:

Khan Academy [Probability](http://www.khanacademy.org/#probability) and [Statistics](http://www.khanacademy.org/#statistics)
Online Statistics Education: An Interactive Multimedia Course of Study http://onlinestatbook.com/
CMU Open Learning Initiative [Statistics](https://oli.web.cmu.edu/openlearning/forstudents/freecourses/statistics)
Introduction to Statistical Thought [Book](http://www.math.umass.edu/~lavine/Book/book.pdf)

Also, if you take ml-class you might be interested in: http://www.pgm-class.org/

Edit (just a few more links):
mathematicalmonk's [probability & ML](http://www.youtube.com/user/mathematicalmonk/videos?view=pl)
All of statistics [Book](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-statistics/)
Kardi Teknomo's Tutorials (EPIC SUFF): http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/index.html

Comment: see also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks

Comment: and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485/mathematical-statistics-videos

Answer (score 1):

Great that you have signed up for the ML class. Actually, there are plenty of resources on learning statistics online.

To begin with, the CRAN website is excellent. Another great resource is SAS software's documentation. Thirdly, there is MIT opencourseware. Also, if you want free stat softwares, apart from R, there are many of them on this website:

www.statpages.org

Answer (score 1):

You can try searching MIT's OCW - http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm
or Academic Earth - http://academicearth.org/
for relevant statistical lectures.