# A roadmap to learn statistics if one has background in mathematics

Tags: self-study

I am graduated from mathematics but my degree did not contain any statistics courses. What kind of road map would one suggest to learn statistics if my next goal would be to learn statistics so well that I could help bachelor thesis writers to do the data analysis? For example, is it enough to study the books *Methods and Applications of Linear Models: Regression and the Analysis of Variance*, *Statistical Inference* and *Introduction to Practice of Statistics*?

Comment: Closely related: [Mathematician wants the equivalent knowledge to a quality stats degree](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6538/mathematician-wants-the-equivalent-knowledge-to-a-quality-stats-degree).

Comment: I was in this kind of situation 9 years ago. I am still reading... the title you quote seem ok to start with. Among my favorites, Davison's *Statistical Models*, Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Start with the standard math statistics and probability texts, whatever is in fashion these days will work. You can get the titles from a syllabi of good universities, e.g. MIT OCW project.

Comment: Better to give full references; there are lots of books with similar titles. Are you after more theoretical or more applied works? Thesis writers in what areas? For example, some application areas are using logistic regression (or other GLMs) these days, even at undergrad level. If you were helping econometricians I'd likely give different advice to if you were helping biologists and different advice again for psych majors.

Comment: (ctd) ... You'll probably be little use to an econometrician if you don't know about sandwich estimators or ADF tests, for example, but they probably won't care about factor analysis...

Comment: The one who asked help was psychologist. I like more about theoretical works but of course I need some applied skills as well like learning R.