# Best book for theory of probability and statistics

Tags: references

I need a proof based book to study theory of probability and statistics. I have read that one of the best is Mood & Graybill. I just want that it is proof-based, rigurous, and it talks about probability, statistics, and statistical inference.

Comment: Have you searched our site for recommendations?  Most likely you will find what you're looking for at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6538/mathematician-wants-the-equivalent-knowledge-to-a-quality-stats-degree/7477#7477.

Comment: There are at least 3 editions of this classic statistics text, the most recent (1963 ?) with Boes as co-author. Totally pre-computer age, but rigorous. Some messy proofs are left to exercises. Many problems are non-trivial and rewarding. No answers, as I recall.