# Statistics for Engineers resource request

Tags: references

*I have checked [Introduction to statistics for mathematicians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414/introduction-to-statistics-for-mathematicians) question. That is not what I am asking.*

---

I was looking at some book review on the web about statistics. Stat books seems to be written with specific topics on mind. What book contain both theory and takes intuitive approach to teach these following topics(**No reference type book please**)?

1. Central tendency and dispersion
2. Basics of probability(Bayes’ Theorem, Chebyshev’s Inequality)
3. Random variables and probability Distribution
4. Linear Regression and Correlation
5. Test of Significance

I have the book [how to lie with statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393310728) which seems a excellent book to strengthen some concept. Also, next year I am going to take a course titled as **Theory of Statistics**. So, I am not looking for very rigor book ATM. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you say your mathematical maturity is? Are you comfortable with lots of integrals,derivatives, and proofs?

Comment: Application(not calculation) of calculus is good. Proofs? I do not know my level. Consider as an advanced beginner on it ;) @RayVelcoro

Comment: I would recommend this book: http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Statistics-Engineers-Scientists-Edition/dp/0321629116

Comment: @RustyStatistician seems like the book I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are some non-geeky, enjoyable books on data science and statistics:

- [The Signal and the Noise](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/159420411X) by Nate Silver.
- [Keeping Up with the Quants](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/142218725X)
- [Data Smart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/111866146X)
- [Predictive Analytics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118356853): The Power to Predict Who Will Click, Buy, Lie, or Die
- [Automate This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D9T9IQG): How Algorithms Came to Rule Our World
- [The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/0961392142)
- [Dataclysm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385347375): Who We Are (When We Think No One's Looking)

Finally, in case you are a programmer, this is a must-read:

[Programming Collective Intelligence](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/0596529325/)

Comment: +1 Very good quality book list. I don't know whether it is okay here to accept answer which isn't being asked. :)

Comment: @silentboy It is okay.  But, you might want to wait some more time before doing so. There might be more nice answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in statistics for Engineers, one of my favorite resources is [Miller & Freund's Probability and Statistics for Engineers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321986245)  The linked copy is the latest edition (as of this writing).  Earlier editions for personal study should prove more than adequate.  This book contains, in a readable and usable manner, everything you are looking for.

Other worthwhile books for engineering statistics would include (but not limited to):

- [Machinery's Handbook](http://new.industrialpress.com/machinery-s-handbook.html) published by Industrial Press.
- Introduction to Statistical Quality Control by Douglas C. Montgomery
- Quality Control by Dale H. Besterfield
- Implementing Six Sigma by Forrest W. Breyfogle III
- Tool and Manufacturing Engineers Handbook: Desk Edition
- Tool and Manufacturing Engineers Handbook: Volume 4: Quality Control and Assembly
- Tool and Manufacturing Engineers Handbook: Volume 7: Continuous Improvement

Departing from books based on the theory and math (but still with a fair amount in them), in the name of "Statistics for Engineers" the following resources are also valuable:

- The Six Sigma Handbook by Thomas Pyzdek (great information in general, but has a focus on how to use Minitab for statistics)
- Computational Statistics handbook with MATLAB by Martinez and Martinez
- Applied Statistics: using SPSS, STATISTICA, MATLAB, and R by Joaquim P. Marques de Sá
- Graphing Data with R by John Jay Hilfinger (Unlike most books on the subject, this is more about using R's data visualization methods, but still briefly covers conducting various tests and data manipulation.)

(As an aside, most functions that can be done in MATLAB can also be done in [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with no change to the code.  Changes required in Octave are well documented on their site and in their packages, all of which are free.)