# Online course for inferential statistics

Tags: references, inference

Having graduated in econometrics I am now working as a Data Science Consultant. I would like to gain a deeper knowledge of (theory of) inferential statistics. Is there any recommendable online course/book/slide material in this area.

I would like to gain a deeper understanding of concepts like:

- Cramer-Rao Lower Bound
- Chapman-Robbins Bound
- Rao-Blackwell Theorem
- Central Limit theorem
- etc.

Note: I do not need basic definitions as I am using statistics and econometrics for ~5 years already. My aim is to gain an understanding of the underlying theory.

Comment: Have a look at the answers (and links) here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414/introduction-to-statistics-for-mathematicians

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at :

https://www.coursera.org/specializations/statistics

Im pretty sure the quality is on point as I have done similar courses from Coursera.

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer to offer more detail about what is on offer; at present it's almost a bare link. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) under "Provide context for links".

Comment: This course your mentioned is for newbies with little or no background in mathematics and statistics.