# Statistics books with applications in quantitative finance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

I am a Pure Maths PhD. As I would like to break into quantitative researcher  jobs after graduation, I need to pick up statistics, programming and quantitative finance finance.

I have been reading time series analysis by Hamilton and Box Jenkins et al. Also, statistics and Data Analysis for Financial Engineering by Ruppert and Matterson.

I think I need to improve on my statistics background. So may I know what statistics  books should I use that have applications in finance?

Comment: Hi: if you're reading hamilton's text and can follow it, then there's no need for you to get a statistics book. OTOH, by statistics book, do you mean a mathematical statistics text or a linear models-regression type text or a multivariate statistics text ?

Comment: Maybe all of them? Actually I am not sure what can be applied in quantitative finance. As long as it can be applied in quantitative finance, then I am interested to learn it. .

Comment: I believe cointegration is not covered in Hamilton's text but it is widely used in quantitative finance, especially algorithmic trading.

Comment: I think my interest is more towards to Statistical analysis in quantitative finance.

Comment: Do you think that my question is better suited to quantitative finance stack exchange?

Comment: Hi: I don't know statistics books that are also quant finance. your best bet is to look at time series- finance texts or econometrics texts. you could sent to quant finance but cross posting is frowned upon so it's best to start a new question. co- integration is definitely covered in hamilton.

Comment: get CFA level 1, nothing will be more useful than this

Comment: @Aksakal I agree with you if my financial situation allows it.

Comment: This post might be useful:  [Introduction to statistics for mathematicians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414/introduction-to-statistics-for-mathematicians)

Answer (score 1):

1. David Ruppert, David S. Matteson *Statistics and Data Analysis for Financial Engineering: with R examples* covers some useful models for QF, both in the sense of time series analysis (e.g. GARCH) and the sense of assessing the values of firms (e.g. Fama-French).
2. Marcos Lopez de Prado *Advances in Financial Machine Learning* is basically a treasure map if you happen to have tens of millions of dollars to invest in building a QF trading house.

Answer (score 0):

While not exclusively about finance, these two books cover important applications and statistical concepts :

1. [Essentials of Stochastic Processes](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/EOSP/EOSP2E.pdf).
2. [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/).